# How to setup muliple cron job every 3 hours but not simultaenously?

Tags: linux, cron

I need to run cron jobs during the following times:

1st job: 1PM 4PM 7PM etc..

2nd job: 1:15PM 4:15PM 7:15PM etc..

3nd job: 1:30PM 4:30PM 7:30PM etc..

As you can see each job run every 3 hours but each job needs to have 15 minutes "break time" before running to next job.

Answer (score 3):

```
0 */3 * * * (blah)
15 */3 * * * (blah2)
30 */3 * * * (blah3)
```

Sounds like you're setting yourself up for a race condition though. What if something runs more than 15 minutes?

Comment: more than 15 minutes is unlikely in what I'm doing but if it happens it won't do damage.

Comment: Additional question: how about if there are more jobs that starts say 2PM or 2:15 or 2:30 or 2:45, etc?

Comment: @imb As long as they don't hit the same stuff, it shouldn't matter. If it's all the same job, you'll probably want to explicitly state the hours (like Ary did it).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the right way. Try with this:

```
0 1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22 * * * /path/to/job1.sh
15 1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22 * * * /path/to/job2.sh 
30 1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22 * * * /path/to/job2.sh
```